# AngularJS ng-selected Issue

Tags: angularjs

I have a multi-select. I have two two different arrays. I want to multi-select comes with selected values.

I want to search `ng-repeat id` from array if found then it becomes true and value will come with selected.

**My AngularJS Code**

```
<script>
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

      $scope.name = "John Brad";

      $scope.important_selection = {
                  "error": false,
                  "client_data": {
                  "important": [
                      {
                          "id": 10,
                          "name": "Socially Responsible"
                      },
                      {
                          "id": 8,
                          "name": "LBGT"
                      },
                      {
                          "id": 4,
                          "name": "Education"
                      },
                      {
                          "id": 2,
                          "name": "Retirement"
                      }
                  ]
                },
                "status_code": 200
              };

    $scope.importants_series = {
                "error": false,
                "important": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "name": "Investment"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "name": "Retirement"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "name": "Insurance"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 4,
                        "name": "Education"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 5,
                        "name": "Tax"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 6,
                        "name": "Estate"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 7,
                        "name": "Business"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 8,
                        "name": "LBGT"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 9,
                        "name": "Offshore"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 10,
                        "name": "Socially Responsible"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 11,
                        "name": "Divorce"
                    }
                ],
                "status_code": 200
            };          
    });
    </script>
```

**My HTML Code**

```
<select name="important[]" class="form-control" multiple="" required>
        <option ng-selected="important_selection.important.find(item => item.id === important.id)" ng-repeat="important in importants_series.important" value="{{important.id}}">{{important.name}}</option>
    </select>
```

Now I want to search id in array and if true then it will be selected.
I have issue in `ng-selected`

`Plunker Link for more details` : https://plnkr.co/edit/BUnUNqr0IevJ5BkslZNM?p=preview

Any Help will be appreciating thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `ng-options` and `ng-model` in `select` for easy data binding.

```
<select name="important[]" class="form-control" multiple="" required 
    ng-options="important.name for important in importants_series.important" 
    ng-model="important_selection.client_data.important"></select>
```

Unfortunately `ng-model` only checks for object reference equality, so we need additional step to reassigning the data from the selection array itself

```
  var oldArray = $scope.important_selection.client_data.important;

  $scope.important_selection.client_data.important = [];

  oldArray.forEach(function(item) {
    var refItem = $scope.importants_series.important.find(function(i) {
      return i.id == item.id;
    });

    $scope.important_selection.client_data.important.push(refItem);
  });
```

Or you can assign it to a new array instead.

[Working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ujc1jN141UiOP5fOTxeb?p=preview)